# Transit through Austria without a stopover - covid-19

Tags: covid-19, austria, hungary, vienna

I plan to fly from Israel to Hungary via Austria, on this route: Flight from
Israel to Vienna> and then a taxi ride from Vienna to Budapest.

In the Corona Regulations of Austria I see listed:
"Transit through Austria without a stopover, which also applies to exclusively indispensable interruptions, provided that a departure is ensured."

How can they ensure I'm leaving?

Are they able to enforce it? And how?

Do I have to present any document / proof that I am leaving? If so, which?

Will they let me leave the airport after signing a declaration that I am leaving Austria and not staying there? Or will they put difficulties on me?

Comment: Do you fullfill the entry conditions for Hungary (precondition for any transit)? Will you have some form of contract showing that you will be picked up at the airport and directly driven to the Hungarian border? Out of personal curiosity: what estimate do you have what the over 240 km taxi drive will cost?

Comment: I think (but am not entirely sure) that transit here refers to staying airside. Since you plan to enter Austria, I would assume that you would need to look at the criteria for entering Austria. To answer if that's possible, I think we might need to know about citizenship (because not everyone is allowed entry into Austria per [the IATA TravelCentre](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php))

Comment: According to the rules of the corona of Hungary I can enter. I want to get organized in advance and know what documents, if any, need to be presented in Austria.
  The price is about 200 euros.

Comment: Flying to Budapest instead would be a lot cheaper and easier. Why is this not an option?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.